# Keep application functionality with an offline microservice in angular

Tags: angular, google-chrome, electron, service-worker, web-worker

I am working on an Angular project that runs on electron. Currently, I have a microservice which i send simple post requests to regularly from my client using fetch API. I want my application to function regularly when this microservice is offline, as i only send requests to it from my client and dont require a response.
However, when i send these requests they remain in a pending state indefinitely (which can be seen in the network tab in the dev tools) and accumulate quickly which causes the io thread to reach its capacity and doesnt allow requests from my server to succeed, causing the data to stop updating in the ui. The following error is thrown when all requests start to fail:
ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES

I thought to use a web worker, however, preflight requests are still sent from the io thread and because they do not recieve a response they are sent for every request and still accumulate quickly.
Another idea was to use a Server to intercept these requests and return an error if the server connection is not available, however i'm not sure this suits my purpose.
Are there other ways to isolate the communication with this microservice or to resolve the pending status of the requests? Is it possible to intercept the requests without a service worker?

EDIT: also tried using rxjs forFetch and race which canceled the requests but the prefetch requests did not fail and stayed in pending. Still looking for a solution to this

Comment: Which angular and Chrome version do you use?

Comment: @KostasNitaf I'm using angular 12.2.13 and chrome 103.0.5060.134. I can't update the version at the moment

Comment: This might help you: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22324

Comment: so you just need to cancel your fetch requests after a timeout, let's say if server didn't respond in 10 seconds, you consider it offline and cancel request. You can achieve this with fetch AbortController, or, since you are using Angular and have RxJs, with `race`

Comment: @KostasNitaf thank you for your response! this is discussing a scenario in which chrome cancels the request and the HTTP request observable does not receive a signal. However, it seems that the request stays active in chrome in my case. It sends the request (through fetch API) and remains in a pending state.